# How to turn WordPress into a paid member site

Tags: subscription

I need a plugin which adds a few abilities to WordPress.

I want to create a site with the exact same structure like woothemes.com. A user can buy a single theme (paid one time) or a membership subscription (all themes, paid every month).

However what the user buys he becomes a member and can download his stuff.

I hope someone knows a good plugin.

Comment: This has been asked a lot, just look at the sidebar--> or so a search..

Answer (score 1):

Check below link for more options.
http://www.bloggermint.com/2011/08/5-best-wordpress-membership-plugin-to-start-a-membership-website/
Another link
http://wp-member.com/

Answer (score 0):

I'm a fan of s2member for something free: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/s2member/
Premium version: http://www.s2member.com/